# Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop cannot be logged in

Tags: 14.04, login

I got unable to log in to Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop. When I try to log in, the display come back to login menu. I would like to fix it.

- I cannot log in when I choose *"Ubuntu (default)"*.
- I can log in when I choose *Openbox* on login menu, but a dialog "System Program Problem is detected" is displayed.
- It is same when I try with other users.
- I tried to delete *.Xauthority* and *.ICEauthority*, but it wasn't solved.
- I tried `unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity`, but it wasn't solved.
- Just before this problem happened, I was trying to make this machine able to use vnc. After I restarted it to check it, this problem happened. But I don't know if it is related to this problem because this machine hasn't restarted for a long time.
- *.xsession-errors* is as below. This file seems to be renewed when I try to log in on *"Ubuntu (default)"*

I appreciate any information for the solution.

```
.xsession-errors

Script for fcitx started at run_im.
Script for fcitx started at run_im.
(INFO-13768 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-notificationitem.conf
(INFO-13768 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-xkb.conf
(INFO-13768 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-dbus.conf
(INFO-13768 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-ipc.conf
(INFO-13768 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-spell.conf
(INFO-13768 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-x11.conf
(INFO-13768 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-xim.conf
(INFO-13768 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-kimpanel-ui.conf
(INFO-13768 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-chttrans.conf
(INFO-13768 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-imselector.conf
(INFO-13768 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-vk.conf
(INFO-13768 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-remote-module.conf
(INFO-13768 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-xkbdbus.conf
(INFO-13768 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-clipboard.conf
(INFO-13768 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-freedesktop-notify.conf
(INFO-13768 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-classic-ui.conf
(INFO-13768 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-lua.conf
(INFO-13768 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-fullwidth-char.conf
(INFO-13768 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-keyboard.conf
(INFO-13768 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-mozc.conf
(INFO-13768 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-quickphrase.conf
(INFO-13768 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-punc.conf
(INFO-13768 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-autoeng.conf
(INFO-13768 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-unicode.conf

(process:13816): Indicator-Power-WARNING **: Fail to query backlight devices.

** (process:13817): CRITICAL **: bluez.vala:104: GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.NoSuchAdapter: No such adapter

(zeitgeist-datahub:13819): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(zeitgeist-datahub:13819): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
nm-applet-Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon

(openbox:13702): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 29 was not found when attempting to remove it

(openbox:13702): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 54 was not found when attempting to remove it

(process:13926): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
** Message: Unable to use GNOME Shell's builtin screenshot interface, resorting to fallback X11.

(gnome-terminal:14024): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_get: the format string may not contain '&' (key 'monospace-font-name' from schema 'org.gnome.desktop.interface'). This call will probably stop working with a future version of glib.

(process:14079): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

(openbox:13702): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 125 was not found when attempting to remove it
```